# Use keyboard shortcuts from VBA to trust VBA object model

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to programmatically enable access to the VBA object model using macros, but I simply do not understand the answers that I have found through Google.

As such I decided to try using keyboard shorcuts. For example, in my language if I press:

Alt -> F -> I -> C -> TAB -> T -> I -> I -> I -> TAB -> V

Then I have successfully enabled the setting to trust the VBA project model.

Is this approach completely idiotic?

Is there an easier way to enable the setting with actual coding rather than what I am trying to do here (I can see cases where my method would likely unreliable)?

And if my idea isn't as bad as it looks, then is there a way to carry it out?

Sites visited:

http://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/macro-to-enable-trust-access-to-the-VBA-project-object-model/ (Understandable, but too unreliable)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/ (Might as well be gibberish to me)

Comment: It is unethical to do this without the user's permission and could potentially be used for serious harm.  If you do not understand the code that you found to accomplish this task (a quick google search finds complete code to do this, although it also contains ethics disclaimers), then I'm not sure what you are trying to do by changing the trust settings.  Perhaps your end result is achievable without changing the trust settings.  I would recommend posting the real problem that you are having and possibly there could be other solutions.

Comment: I tried out the code found here http://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/macro-to-enable-trust-access-to-the-VBA-project-object-model/ but the whole SendKeys thing is too unreliable and definitely does not click anything even close to enabling the setting

Comment: SendKeys is the only way this will work, otherwise, there is no security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly discouraged. The whole idea behind trusting option is requiring user permission. Imagine how "secure" it would be if every macro could automatically trust itself.

**Edit:** though it may be possible with mentioned `SendKeys` method, you will still need a click from the user to enable macros, i.e. when they open your file.

Comment: It is possible using SendKeys as the OP has found on another website.  Your overall point, though, is very true.

Comment: Of course, it is sort of an infinite loop, but I had to make sure. I know that the whole thing is considered unetical and unsafe, but the end users in this case will be exceptionally helpless, so asking them to enable the setting themselves might prove... difficult. Anyway, thanks for debunking it. I'll try a different approach with pictures and explanations for them.